# Creating a variable from a condition with more than 2 arguments

Tags: r, conditional-statements

Following is an easy version of what I'm trying to do. I have the following vector:

```
wage = 1:10 # Generate a sequence from 1 to 10
```

And I want to create another vector `wage_level` such that:

(i) `wage_level` is `"low"` if `wage` less than `5`

(ii) `wage_level` is `normal` if `wage` is equal to `5`

(iii) `wage_level` is `high` if `wage` is greater than `5`

I know I can use nested `ifelse` statements to do it, however, as I pointed out earlier, this is but a simplified version of what I really want to do because I have about 15 alternatives.

**Edit**

The answer provided below makes use of the `cut()` function, which actually works well in many cases. However, it does not seem to "work" in my case. Following is the detailed explanation.

I was able to use the `cut()` function to create the `wage_level` vector:

```
wage = runif(10, 1, 10) # Randomly generate 10 values between 1 and 10

# Here I use the cut() function
wage_level = cut(wage,
                 breaks = c(1, 4, 6, 10),
                 labels = c("low", "normal", "high"),
                 include.lowest = TRUE)
> wage
[1] 5.522422 4.793292 8.161671 5.480415 1.396909 3.403013 4.940242 7.762142 6.364159 4.603998

> wage_level
[1] normal normal high   normal low    low    normal high   high   normal
Levels: low normal high
```

Now, let's suppose I want to use the `wage_level` vector to create another vector (the `rating` vector) using the `cut()` function. The condition to create the `rating` vector is as follows:

(i) `rating` is `"1"` if `wage_level` less than `"low"`

(ii) `rating` is `2` if `wage_level` is equal to `"normal"`

(iii) `rating` is `3` if `wage_level` is greater than `"high`

My problem is that using the `cut()` function will not make the `rating` vector a `numeric` vector will the values of my choice. The following code does not work:

```
rating = cut(as.numeric(wage_level),
                 breaks = c(0, 1, 2, 3),
                 labels = c(1.2, 6.5, 8.9),
                 include.lowest = TRUE)

> as.numeric(rating)
 [1] 2 2 3 2 1 1 2 3 3 2
```

I mainly have two problems here:

(i) I would have preferred a way to use the actual strings (i.e. "low", "normal" and "high") instead of the labels indexes

(ii) The values in the `rating` vector have nothing to do with the values I specified.

Any other method to achieve the desired result?

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: You're probably looking for `cut()`

Comment: @ndoogan is spot on.  I've found that working with a large amount of interval breaks, it is helpful to have the `breaks` and `labels` be their own variables, often created with `seq` and `paste0`

Comment: @ndoogan Please, I edited my question, would you please take a look?

Comment: @RicardoSaporta Please, I edited my question, would you please take a look?

Comment: @SavedByJESUS Why not create `rating` using the original numeric variable `wage`? Or perhaps work with creating `wage_level` as an *ordered factor* before using it to create `rating`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
wage<-1:10
cut(wage,breaks=c(0,4,5,10),include.lowest=T,labels=c("low","normal","high"))
# [1] low    low    low    low    normal high   high   high   high   high  
#Levels: low normal high
```

What if the vector isn't ordered? No difference:

```
wage <- runif(10,1,10)
wage
# [1] 8.535146 4.964819 7.228050 9.150132 6.369952 8.451137 8.022293 7.621226
# [9] 1.070368 5.931904

cut(wage,breaks=c(0,4,5,10),include.lowest=T,labels=c("low","normal","high"))
# [1] high   normal high   high   high   high   high   high   low    high
```

Though, notice that the `normal` factor is applied to values between 4 and 5. If you're *really* working with reals, then looking for exactly 5 might be an odd choice.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @ndoogan. This is very helpful; however, what should I do if the data is not arranged in an increasing order just like in the example? What if I had `wage = runif(10, 1, 10)`?

Comment: Why do you think that matters?

Comment: @SavedByJESUS I agree with themel. Try it and see. It will work fine.